# Trying to make a 2D Spring

Tags: c#, 2d, unity

Still a Beginner at Unity 5 and this time I am trying to make a Spring.

The spring would act as you'd expect. Something comes in with a direction and force, so you bounce it the opposite direction of the way it came in. Something like this:

[image]

But for some reason my player object doesn't interact with my Spring. It goes right through it as if they are on separate layers.

[image]

As you see above it falls right through. Now here is my setup:

[image]

Finally the Spring Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BounceOnContact : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collisionInfo)
    {
        Rigidbody2D rBody = collisionInfo.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Vector2 vel = rBody.velocity;
        float mag = vel.magnitude;
        rBody.AddForce(Vector2.Reflect(vel, collisionInfo.contacts[0].normal) * mag, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure what I'm missing. The player object should hit my spring right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Spring object's `BoxCollider2D` has the Is Trigger box checked, which means that you need to check for collisions with `OnTriggerEnter2D`, rather than `OnCollisionEnter2D`.

Comment: But then I lose the `contacts[0].normal` part that I'd get from Collision2D. Can I get that some other way by having a Collider2D?

Comment: @Vipar No, not directly. Why not just uncheck Is Trigger and use `OnCollisionEnter2D` then? It should work.

Comment: I don't know entirely how these things work, which is why I ask :P I'm still at a beginner level :) But yeah that seemed to do it. Now to adjust. Thanks.